# VS Code syntax highlighting Python f-strings

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I've been using VS Code for Python for a while now, but after all this time I still haven't figured out how to syntax highlight my f-strings. I've seen screenshots of other people who have them highlighted properly, but mine look like this:

[image]

Is this something I have to manually change in my color scheme?

Comment: I just installed the Python extension fresh, and I have proper syntax highlighting for f-strings. Maybe try reinstalling the extension/make sure you have the correct one installed. I used the one by Microsoft, version `v2021.11.1422169775`.

Comment: I didn't configure it manully, but I have it. but i think it's in python extension by default try uninstall and install again

Comment: with theme `Light+` I have the syntax highlighting in f-strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can it output the correct result? In other words, f-string can work?

Have you tried to switch the color theme?

And can you open the `Command Palette` to execute the command of `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes` to get this:

[image]

Can you find the `meta.fstring.python` like the above picture?

This could be provided by the `Built-in` extension of `Python Language Basic` or `MagicPython` extension and so on. So could you disable all the python related extensions then only enable the Python and `Built-in` extension of `Python Language Basic` to make a try?

Comment: They do actually work. Stangely enough, the 'meta.fstring.python' scope does not show. I only have 'constant.other.placeholder.python', 'string.quoted.double.single-line.python', and 'source.python'

Comment: @Matthijs Kramer Have you tried to only enable the python extension? And which version you are using of python?

Comment: @Matthijs Kramer Which language server you are using? pylance?

Comment: @Matthijs Kramer Very sorry for that, could you submit a bug on GitHub under vscode-python?

Comment: Disabling a bunch of extensions one at a time showed that the culprit was my Darcula color theme extension... Thanks for suggesting disabling extensions!

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the theme of VSCode. I usually use the [Github theme](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.github-vscode-theme) and I can see proper syntax highlight. Also, make sure all the necessary extensions for python are installed.

[Screenshot from VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pDvy.jpg)